# Account deletion job based on object relations

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, scheduled-apex, apexrest

I have a requirement for creating a job for deleting the accounts that do not have related cases, opportunity, Lead.

The 3 objects can also change in future and new object to be checked can be added or the existing one can also be deleted. Hence I have created a custom label and stored the Object API names in it.

Custom Label: `objectsToConsider - Case, Opportunity, Lead`

If the Account has a related contact, it should not be considered for deletion.
A custom label named `isJobEnabled` is used to enable to disable the job. The value can be true or false.

The job should also not run in between 12 AM to 6 AM CST.
So far I have written below logic but it looks like I am missing something.
Any other way to execute this use case or repair the existing logic will be helpful.

Snippet:

```
global class AccountDeletionJob implements Schedulable {

   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
       // Check if the job is enabled
       if (Boolean.valueOf(System.Label.isJobEnabled)) {
           // list of objects to consider
           String objectsToConsider = System.Label.objectsToConsider;

           // find accounts with only related contacts
           List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

           for (Account acc : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account]) {
               // Check if the account has only one related contact
               if (acc.Contacts.size() == 1) {
                   // Check if the account has no specified objects related
                   Boolean hasSpecifiedObjects = false;
                   for (String objectName : objectsToConsider.split(',')) {
                       if (acc.getSObjects(objectName).size() > 0) {
                           hasSpecifiedObjects = true;
                           break;
                       }
                   }

                   // If the account has no specified objects, add it to the list for update
                   if (!hasSpecifiedObjects) {
                       accountsToUpdate.add(acc);
                   }
               }
           }

           // Exclude running the job from 12 am to 6 am CST
           DateTime currentDateTime = System.now();
           Time currentTime = currentDateTime.time();
           Time startTime = Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0);
           Time endTime = Time.newInstance(6, 0, 0, 0);
           if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime < endTime) {
               // Logic to skip job execution during the specified time range
               return;
           }

           //logic to perform the job, e.g., delete the accounts
           if (!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
               delete accountsToUpdate;
               system.debug('accountsToUpdate::: '+accountsToUpdate);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has a lot of problems, such as not caring about governor limits, not actually checking for the related objects, and so on. Here would be my attempt to fix most of the problems. One thing I've noted here is that the requirement to not run between midnight and six in the morning is that you need to consider time zones. I've excluded that for this exercise. The result is a concise query that can handle millions of records if necessary. I've also kept it as your own code with using Custom Labels, but ideally, you should consider [Custom Metadata Types](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=5).

```
public class AccountDeletionJob implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<Account> {
  public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
    Database.executeBatch(this);
  }
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    String[] objectsToConsider = Label.objectsToConsider.split(',');
    String[] filters = new String[] { 'WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)' };
    for(String objectToConsider: objectsToconsider) {
      // If we had custom objects, we'd need to determine AccountId vs custom field
      filters.add(' AND Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM '+objectToConsider+')');
    }
    return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id FROM Account '+String.join(filters,''));
  }
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
    delete scope;
  }
  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

  }
}
```